# Check if logged in within the last week

Tags: php, sql, max

How do I return logins of users that have not logged in for over a week? I have a logins table with the following columns: id, user_id, email, access, and logged. I would like to return users that have not logged in within the last 1 week, however, I would like to return the MAX login date. This seems difficult when using a GROUP BY statement.

[image: Table]

Note: this question is NOT a duplicate, it is a unique problem, as I wish to return the MAX login date.

```
SELECT id, user_id, email, logged, max(logged)
FROM logins
WHERE logged <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have every logged in, you can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, email, max(logged)
FROM logins
GROUP BY user_id, email
HAVING MAX(logged) <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

If you want to include all users, even those who may have never logged in, I might suggest a correlated subquery and `HAVING`.  This assumes you have a users table:

```
select u.*,
       (select MAX(.logged)
        FROM logins l
        WHERE l.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as most_recent_logged
from users u
having most_recent_logged <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Note that this use of the `HAVING` clause is a MySQL extension.  It lets you filter by column aliases even in a non-aggregation query.

Comment: Yes, I have a users table and would like to include all users. However this code returns an error: Unknown column 'u.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user1228907 . . . Use whatever the id column is in `users`.  I name my foreign keys and primary keys the same when possible to avoid confusion.

Comment: most_recent_logged seems to return the same value for each column

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to include users that have not logged in. Firstly you must intially SELECT the table with all users in, rather than logged in users, then at the end you have "OR COUNT(most_recent_logged) = 0":

```
SELECT u.email, u.enabled, l.access, l.logged, u.first_name, u.surname, 
u.telephone_no, s.farm_id, s.farmer,
        (SELECT MAX(logged)
        FROM logins l
        WHERE l.user_id = u.id) as most_recent_logged       
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN logins l on u.id = l.user_id
LEFT JOIN settings s on u.id = s.user_id
WHERE farmer = 1
GROUP BY u.id, u.email DESC
HAVING most_recent_logged <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
OR COUNT(most_recent_logged) = 0
```